# How to get an image to stretch on a multi-screen setup?

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors, desktop-customization

I have 3 monitors (each 1600x1200) setup in a following configuration:

[image]

I have a image that is 4800x1200, thus should neatly fit across three screens.
However, no matter what I tried it won't stretch across the screens.

If I select Fill, it take a third of the entire image and places a copy on each monitor.
If I select Fit, it compresses the image and places a miniature copy of it on each monitor.
If I select Stretch, it compresses 4800x1200 image into 1600x1200 and places it on each monitor.
If I select Tile, it's probably the closest to what I want, but it places left part of the image on my monitor 1, middle part on monitor 2 and right part on monitor 3.  If my main monitor was on the very left, this would work, but I don't like that type of setup.
If I select Center, ...I can't even figure out what's doing here, but it's not usable.

How do I get the image to properly lay out across my monitors?

Comment: `Tile` **is** the correct option. Therefore, your question should be "How do I tile a wallpaper from left to right if my display numbers are not in that order?"

Comment: cool @iglvzx. So maybe cut the 1st third of the image (0 to 16000x) and paste it after the right end.

Comment: @jdh That would be one way, to just edit the image to match the order of the displays.

Comment: Use DisplayFusion

Answer (score 1):

`Tile` **is** the correct option. A workaround would be to edit the image so that it matches your display setup, i.e. instead of `[1|2|3]`, the resulting image could be rearranged as `[3|1|2]`.

Comment: I have over 50 images that I purchased from an artist type site and I have Windows 7 rotating them every 30 minutes.  I am not going to edit all 50 images.  There has to be a better way.